# Undefined methods with Auth() and Auth.php after using Laravel Breeze and LaraTrust

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-breeze, laratrust

l just installed Laravel Breeze and Laratrust to make my multi auth feature. When I opened `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController.php`, without even editing anything yet, Intelephense throws an error:
``Undefined method 'logout'.`
from the code:

```
 public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout(); //has error

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

I then Ctrl+Click the `Auth` class to see where the error could be. It lead me to
`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth.php` with another error:
`Undefined method 'providerIsLoaded'.`

This is the code with the error:

```
 public static function routes(array $options = [])
    {
        if (! static::$app->providerIsLoaded(UiServiceProvider::class)) { //has error
            throw new RuntimeException('In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package.');
        }

        static::$app->make('router')->auth($options);
    }
```

I have not modified anything within these codes. I just received the error upon opening them. So far, it hasn't broken my app or I haven't seen any errors on the web app itself, but I don't want to wait around for them to happen. Can anyone help me please?